# How to find the maxima?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a simple question : Find the maximum value of $\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 }-6x+2 }$

I rewrote ${ x }^{ 2 }-6x+2$ as $(x-3)^{2} - 7$, now when this is min, the original function is max, thus the answer should be $\frac { -1 }{ 7 } $ .

Now a friend asked me that what's wrong in putting $x=0$ in the original equation, you'll get max as $\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $ OR when the denominator is $0$, the max will be infinity and I couldn't give him a proper explanation.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum value of the function $\dfrac{1}{x^2-6x+2}$, since when $(x-3)^2-7$ is small positive, the reciprocal is huge.  And we can make $(x-3)^2-7$ as small positive as we wish, by taking $x$ a tiny bit larger than $3+\sqrt{7}$ or a tiny bit smaller than $3-\sqrt{7}$.

We do have a **local** maximum at $x=3$, since as we move away from $x=3$ in either direction *for a while*, the function $\dfrac{1}{x^2-6x+2}$ decreases. But, as your friend pointed out, we do not have a *global* maximum at $x=3$.

**Remark:** In order to *see* what's happening, nothing is as good as a picture. Use Wolfram Alpha, or some other graphing program, or a graphing calculator, to draw a picture of the curve $y=\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^2-7}$. Everything will become clear.

Comment: But even Wolfram says that the maximum is $-1/7$ and what's wrong in my solution?

Comment: @Hyperbola, draw the graph. A **local** maximum occurs at $(3, -1/7)$ (it is higher than everything nearby), but there is no **global** maximum (it is higher than everything).

Comment: There *is* a local max at $x=3$.  But the singularities at $x=4\pm\sqrt{7}$ must be taken account of when graphing the reciprocal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y=\frac1{x^2-6x+2}$$

$$\implies y\cdot x^2-6y\cdot x+2y-1=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant of the above Quadratic equation must be $\ge0$

i..e, $$(-6y)^2-4y(2y-1)\ge0\implies y(7y+1)\ge0$$

Either $y\ge0$ and $y\ge -\frac17\implies y\ge0$

or  $y\le0$ and $y\le -\frac17\implies y\le -\frac17$

$$\implies -\infty <y\le -\frac17\cup 0\le y<\infty$$